# How to remove content appended to block in parent template?

Tags: inheritance, smarty, template-engine

I have three templates:

**base.tpl**

```
{block name="myBlock"}
    base
{/block}
```

**child.tpl**

```
{extends file="base.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock" append}
    child
{/block}
```

**grandchild.tpl**

```
{extends file="child.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock" append}
    grandchild
{/block}
```

The output when rendering `grandchild.tpl` is

```
base
child
grandchild
```

But I would like to skip the content added by `child.tpl`, so I would like to get this output:

```
base
grandchild
```

Problem is that this needs to be done without changing `base.tpl` and `child.tpl` (both come from a third party), I can't just extend `base.tpl` in `grandchild.tpl`, since there are more blocks with content in `child.tpl` I'd like to have in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should simple change name of the block in `base.tpl` and `grandchild.tpl` and leave `child.tpl` not changed.

**base.tpl**

```
{block name="myBlock2"}
    base
{/block}
```

**child.tpl**

```
{extends file="base.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock" append}
    child
{/block}
```

**grandchild.tpl**

```
{extends file="child.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock2" append}
    grandchild
{/block}
```

Output is now:

> base
>   grandchild

**EDIT - after info from comment that base.tpl also could't be modified**

It seems that the only thing you need to do is removing `append` from `grandchild.tpl` and leave 2 other files unchanged.

**grandchild.tpl**

```
{extends file="child.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock"}
    grandchild
{/block}
```

Output is:

> base
>   grandchild

as you wanted

Comment: I also can't modify `base.tpl`, its also from a third-party... Forgot to mention that, sorry :(

Comment: Why does this work? I thought doing it like this would reset the whole block, all the way up the inheritance tree. But it seems to just override the "append" from `child.tpl`?

Comment: For me that's also quite strange. But it seems that when you don't use append (and probably prepend) the whole content of this block is added except direct parent. You may try add one more `grandgrandchild.tpl` without append and add append to grandchild again. Then the output will be `base child grandgrandchild` so it makes that content of parents except direct parent is used. You can also use `{$smarty.block.parent}` and finally have output for example `base child grandgrandchild grandchild` if you want