# Template inheritance: remove block that was added in grandparent and appended to in parent

Tags: smarty, smarty3

In a smarty template, I have three templates:

**base.tpl**

```
{block name="myBlock"}
    base
{/block}
```

**child.tpl**

```
{extends file="base.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock" append}
    child
{/block}
```

**grandchild.tpl**

```
{extends file="child.tpl"}
{block name="myBlock"}{/block}
```

When rendering `grandchild.tpl`, the output is

```
base
```

So the grandchild-template wants to replace the content of whole block, but only replaces the appended part. How do I delete the whole block?

Related: [How to remove content appended to block in parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213349/how-to-remove-content-appended-to-block-in-parent-template)

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is in `child.tpl` change block definition from:

```
{block name="myBlock" append}
    child
{/block}
```

into:

```
{block name="myBlock"}
    {$smarty.block.parent} child
{/block}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would probably solve the problem. The problem is, that I cannot modify `base.tpl` or `child.tpl` (provided by a third party). Is there still a solution?

Comment: @Jost I don't know if it can be done. I haven't found any other solution to make it work. Only the one above